# Balancer is not available

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, rebalancing

command rebalance is not currently available for execution because role balancer must be in state N/A, but it is in state Busy

I cant start rebalance on cdh 5.16.2.

I search process rebalance
ps -ef | grep balancer
I cant resolve it  (